# PHP: newbie question - parse xml from string?

Tags: xml-parsing

i've googled and found several php extensions for php so i was wondering: 
is there already a built-in support for parsing xml in php?

i'd like to convert my projects from asp to php - i got xml data stored in a database - so i need an xml parser for php which can accept xmldata as string (not load-from-file) - any ideas how to do it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/de/book.simplexml.php)

To be precise: [`simplexml_load_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) — Interprets a string of XML into an object

```
object simplexml_load_string ( string $data [, string $class_name = "SimpleXMLElement" [, int $options = 0 [, string $ns [, bool $is_prefix = false ]]]] )
```

Example:

```
$string = // your XML string
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
```